# Zend Framework 2 - UnitTests

Tags: php, unit-testing, authentication, zend-framework2, zend-test

I want to create a simple access unit test like it is shown [in the tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html#write-the-tests).

My project uses `ZFCUser` for authentication.

As a result my (obviously not authenticated) tester get a `HTTP response` of 302 and not the expected 200.

Any ideas what I can do about it? Thanks!

The code from the tutorial looks like this:

```
public function testAddActionCanBeAccessed()
{
    $this->routeMatch->setParam('action', 'add');

    $result   = $this->controller->dispatch($this->request);
    $response = $this->controller->getResponse();

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

Comment: Procide the code you tested ;) (even if i wont be able to help, other may seeing your tests)

Comment: as i said, its a very simple test by now. i just need to bypass the auth for the tester... and for this problem i dont have any code ;)

Comment: What do you want to test? That your `add` action can be done **when authenticated**? Then you have to mock the authentication service and put an identity in there so you can test your controller accepts the valid auth. Just to be sure: test also the case where the unauthorized request causes a redirect you have now.

Comment: thanks, good idea! is there an easy way to mock the auth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
thanks, good idea! is there an easy way to mock the auth? – Ron
```

I'm posting this as an answer, because its too much to press it into a comment. Yes, there is an easy way to mock the AuthenticationService class. First of all, check the docs on [Stubs / Mocks](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs).

What you need to do is to create the mock from Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService and configure it to pretend to contain an identity.

```
public function testSomethingThatRequiresAuth()
{
    $authMock = $this->getMock('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService');
    $authMock->expects($this->any())
             ->method('hasIdentity')
             ->will($this->returnValue(true));

    $authMock->expects($this->any())
             ->method('getIdentity')
             ->will($this->returnValue($identityMock));

    // Assign $authMock to the part where Authentication is required.
}
```

In this example, a variable `$identityMock` is required to be defined previously. It could be a mock of your user model class or something like that.

Note that I haven't tested it, so it might not work instantly. However, its just supposed to show you the direction.

Comment: sorry for this dumb question but how to i create the connection between the `$authMock` and my function to call? an example would be great!

Comment: @Ron not dumb question. see http://www.afewmorelines.com/mocking-user-identities-in-zf2-action-controller-unit-tests/ if you use serviceLocator to get AuthenticationService.